# Create a reusable user control with custom templates

Tags: wpf, templates

I made a user control, and in my control I have "Title", graphically "Title" is a TextBlock, but I want those who use mon control will have the option to change it, so, the first idea is the create a property "TitleTemplate" that inherits from "DataTemplate", I'm just following the wpf logic, but I cant find any tutorial that can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I have concluded that the best way is the create a **CustomControl**, not a **UserControl**, because, my control is not a composition of other controls, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think, u should read more about *TemplateBinding* and *ContentPresenter*.
I suggest u read this articles:

> [Using Templates to Customize WPF Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163497.aspx)
>   and
>   [Dr.WPF](http://drwpf.com/blog/category/control-templates/)